# How to test that expires/TTL value is set in Mongoose Schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I'm using MongoDB's [TTL Index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/) feature to automatically delete documents (in this case, email verification tokens) after a certain amount of time.

I also use Mongoose, which creates this index via the `expires` property (on the `createdAt` timestamp):

```
const emailVerifiationTokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema<IEmailVerificationToken>({
    userId: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    tokenId: { type: String, required: true },
    createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: () => Date.now(), expires: 43200 },
});
```

**How can I write a test that ensures that I'm setting this value to the correct amount?** There doesn't seem to be a way to access this value from the outside.

I use Jest for testing.

Comment: If you don't trust that Mongoose and MongoDB are well-tested, should you be using them?

Comment: @robertklep I want to protect myself from accidentally deleting that value. How can I do that?

Comment: How could you accidentally delete it? Sounds like a completely different issue tbh.

Comment: @robertklep That's what unit tests are for, right? Protect me from breaking my code. This question is about how to create a unit tests that protects me from removing that important property. What do you feel is wrong about this question?

Comment: _"This question is about how to create a unit tests that protects me from removing that important property"_. That's not what you're asking in your question, at least not how I'm reading it. You're asking how to test that the expired documents get removed from the database properly.

Comment: @robertklep Could you suggest how I can change the question to make clear what I actually mean? I already changed the title.

Comment: From what I understand, you want to test that the `expires` property is properly set in your schema.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it won't be a unittest. It violates at least 2 rules of unittesting - don't test what you don't own, and test individual units in isolation. If you want to test TL index jest is not the best tool. Mongo triggers TTL clean up every minute, so you would need to exercise content of the database at least 1 minute after expected deletion. I would give 2. If you insist of using jest, you will need to pause it for that time which will slow down the whole test suit.

Regardless of the testing framework the test should be something like this:

1. Insert a document with `createdAt` value `new Date() - 43195` so the expected expiration date will be in 5 seconds from now.
2. Get the _id of the document
3. Find the document by _id to confirm it's been saved
4. Wait for 2 minutes
5. Find the document by _id to confirm it's been deleted

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Mongoose's `expires` property creates a [TTL index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/) in MongoDB. We can retrieve this index over the model class by calling `listIndexes` and it contains an `expireAfterSeconds` property:

```
const emailVerificationIndexes = await EmailVerificationToken.listIndexes();
```

outputs something like this:

```
[
   {
      "v":2,
      "key":{
         "_id":1
      },
      "name":"_id_"
   },
   {
      "v":2,
      "key":{
         "createdAt":1
      },
      "name":"createdAt_1",
      "background":true,
      "expireAfterSeconds":43200
   }
]
```

Then we can simply assert that this property has the expected value in a unit test.